# Deserialize JSON to class with other classes inside

Tags: javascript, json

I've seen many posts how to deserialize JSON to class, e.g. `Object.assign(new Class, JSON.parse(json))`, but I wonder is there a nice way to deserialize JSON if it has nested classes inside with class name parameters?

I can have something like:

```
{
    class_name: "MyClass",
    x: 1,
    p: {
       class_name: "OtherClass",
       y: 2
    }
}
```

and classes:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(x, p) {
    this.x = x;
    this.p = p;
  }
}

class OtherClass {
  constructor(y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

What I need to do is to parse this JSON in such way, that I get `MyClass` object which p value will be `OtherClass` object, and I would like to use class_name parameter to achieve this. I know this must be possible, but is there a nice short way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` has an optional [reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) which can be used to initialize and inject your classes.
This is a simple example:

```
var a = `
{
    "class_name": "MyClass",
    "x": 1,
    "p": {
       "class_name": "OtherClass",
       "y": 2
    }
}`

class MyClass {
    constructor(x, p) {
        this.x = x;
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    constructor(y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

const classRegistry = {
    MyClass,
    OtherClass
}

function reviver(_, value) {
    if(value instanceof Object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, 'class_name')) {
        clazz = classRegistry[value.class_name];
        if(clazz) {
            let {class_name:_, ...valueWithoutClassName} = value;
            return Object.assign(new clazz, valueWithoutClassName)
        }
    }
    return value;
}
console.log(JSON.parse(a, reviver));
```

Output:

```
MyClass { x: 1, p: OtherClass { y: 2 } }
```

`classRegistry` lists the allowed classes, and maps them to the class constructor.
Function `reviver` is called by `JSON.parse` for each property, it checks if the property value has `class_name`, if so:

- It checks that `class_name` has an allowed value.
- Makes a copy of the value without class_name property.
- Creates an instance of the specified class, and fill-in it.